# Laravel eloquent has_many_and_belongs_to sync() without writing to database

Tags: forms, synchronization, laravel, has-and-belongs-to-many, eloquent

In short, does Laravel's eloquent have something like it's `sync()` functionality that doesn't save the relationships to the database right away?

I have two models

```
Place (id, name, address);
```

and

```
Feature (id, name);
```

These two models has a has_many_and_belongs_to relationship with each other, using the pivot table
`feature_place(place_id, feature_id)`. This works as expected. Now I'm trying trying to build a form for creating a new Place. The form contains a checkbox for each existant Feature. For error handling I want to be able to create a Place object when the form is submitted. I'd like to be able to create my `HABTM` relationship, so I can easily rebuild and fill the form if submission fails (validation error or similar). `sync()` would usually handle the relationships, but since the submission has failed I don't want to insert the Place in the database yet.
Is there an easy way, like `sync()`, to create the relationship between my `Place` and it's `Features` that I can use to repopulate my form on rebuild, without having to write to the database before form submission succeeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to flash the input to the session and then load the old values when the form is rendered.

```
// Somewhere in your post route
if ( $oh_noes_teh_validator_failed )
{
    Input::flash();
    Redirect::to_route( 'my-edit-form' );
}

// Somewhere in your edit route or view
$title = Input::old( 'title', $title );
```

Comment: That will carry over the data, yes, but it will not give me the model structure to be able to build the same form for both 'create new Place' and 'edit existing Place'. I'm currently looking at [link](http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/former/) the Former bundle, to see if that can handle the form building/validation/rebuilding for me. So far it looks promising.